# Show checkmark button when the cell is selected

Tags: swift

I have a button with a checkmark image and I want when the user selects the cell the button to show from the hide state it was.

I have already configured the collectionView and just need to make the option to show the checkmark button from the hide state to a selected state only for the cell selected.

Also if there is a possibility to let the checkmark button shown only on the first cell when the data is loaded.

Code from VC:

```
var properties =  connectedProperties(StatusCode: 0)
var propertiesNew =  connectedProperties(StatusCode: 0)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetchAndReloadDataConnectedProperties()
}

func fetchAndReloadDataConnectedProperties(){
    APICallerGET.shared.connectedPropertiesOfAccount(for: APICallerGET.shared.token!) { [self] (result, error) in
        
        switch result?.StatusCode {
        case 0:
            
            self.propertiesNew = result!
            self.properties = self.propertiesNew
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                result.first?.isSelected = true
                self.CollectionView.reloadData()
            }
        case 1:
            print("error")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    return properties.Result?.count ?? 0
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "dashboardCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? dashboardCollectionViewCell else { return UICollectionViewCell() }
    
    let currentPropertie = properties.Result?[indexPath.row]
    
    cell.nameSurnameLabel?.text = currentPropertie?.completeName

    // cell.checkMarkButton  <--- the button i need to show when the user selects the cell

    cell.containerForCell.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(1)
    
    return cell
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    let selectedCell = properties.Result?[indexPath.row]
    
    print(selectedCell!)
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    
    return CGSize(width: 185, height: 50)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a variable to store the current selected IndexPath.

```
var selected = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
```

Update your following collectionView delegates.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "dashboardCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? dashboardCollectionViewCell else { return UICollectionViewCell() }
        
     let currentPropertie = properties.Result?[indexPath.row]
        
     cell.nameSurnameLabel?.text = currentPropertie?.completeName

     // Hide or unhide button
     cell.checkMarkButton.isHidden = !(indexPath == selected)
        
     cell.containerForCell.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(1)
        
     return cell

}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
     let previous = selected
     selected = indexPath
        
     collectionView.reloadItems(at: [previous, selected])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to add a property in the object which is in the `Result` array – by the way name it lowercased and declare it non-optional.

```
var isSelected = false
```

after loading the data and before calling `reloadData()` set the property of the first item to `true`

```
result.first?.isSelected = true
```

In `cellForItemAt` show or hide the button depending on `isSelected`

```
if currentPropertie.isSelected {
  // show cell.checkMarkButton  
} else {
  // hide cell.checkMarkButton  
}
```

In `didSelectItemAt` toggle (or set) the property and reload the row

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    properties.result[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
    collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath] )
}
```

Comment: Hey @vadian thanks a lot for your answer man! , I just updated the code and added the api call function so if you can explain where exactly to put your code since I am new to swift and really tried to fix with your answer but I ain't going to achieve anything.